# Ads are cut off on the right

Tags: bug, design

Had a look in chrome dev console, and I think the problem is the 8px padding in div adcm2, class everyonelovesstackoverflow. If I change that to 0 it's fine. (The sidebar, that container, the ad, everything seems to be 220px wide, so there's no room for padding.)

It looks like this:

[image: clipped ad 1] [image: clipped ad 2]

Here a [full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6kHE.jpg) in case it helps.

Comment: wat‍ ‌  ​ ‌‍ ‌  ​

Comment: @Aaronut Added a more obvious example; does that help?

Comment: Also, those screenshots are from a chromebook pixel (high resolution), so I checked on my desktop and see the same thing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VVAwM.png

Comment: Aaand, actually looked at details, seems to just be the ads, not anything else.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now - "ads are cut off" is definitely a more accurate description.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that just doesn't make any sense. I've added a fix to remove this padding to the next version of [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: Comparing to other sites, you're correct that the issue is caused by 8px left padding on `everyonelovesstackoverflow` (I actually asked "wat" too after seeing the class name :)